# Must a IPC method using ports use network sockets?

Tags: linux, sockets, operating-system, ipc

1. In [inter process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (IPC) (see its article in Wikipedia, especially in Linux),

   - If a IPC method  uses port(s), must it be the IPC method using network sockets? Are there IPC methods that use port(s) not IPC via network sockets?
   - Are the ports here transport ports in transport layer?
2. A minor question: In Comer's Operating System Design: the Xinu
   Approach, does "port"   have a different definition?

   > Xinu uses the term inter-process communication port to refer to a rendezvous point  through  which  processes  can  exchange 
   >   messages.

   Is "port" in Comer's book not transport port in transport layer?

   Is the IPC method using "port" here not
   the IPC method using network socket? (I guess the definition of "port" is different in
   Xinu than in Linux?)

   Is there only one "rendezvous point" in IPC between two processes, or each process has a "rendezvous point"? (Contrast to that in socket IPC, each process has a socket.)

   Are there IPC methods in Linux that   use "rendezvous point"?

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia is overly generalizing, and it is hard to make practical things of it. For instance, there are portless sockets from AF_UNIX family. Port is a word with thousands of meanings, so asking 'are there IPC communication layers which use port, but not AF_INET sockets' is somewhat moot. Their might be, I can provide you with one (being adequately paid, of course). This implementation will have 'ports' defined for it.

Comment: (1) You said I was asking 'are there IPC communication layers which use port, but not AF_INET sockets', but I was asking "If a IPC method uses port(s), must it be the IPC method using **network** sockets?" (2) "Their might be, I can provide you with one (being adequately paid, of course). " I don't need you to provide one, but to explain somehow.

Comment: (3) Especially my questions in part 2:  (a) Is there only one "rendezvous point" in IPC between two processes, or each process has a "rendezvous point"? (Contrast to that in socket IPC, each process has a socket.)
(b) Are there IPC methods in Linux that use "rendezvous point"?

Comment: Again, what do you mean by 'using ports'? What is a 'port'?

Comment: In my part 1, "ports" mean "transport ports"

Comment: where are you getting this definiton from? Also, what is your definition of 'rendezvous point'?

Comment: Have read my post? I didn't find its def in the book I mentioned. but you are free to look them up in your favorite OS books.

Comment: You want me to explain to you what a random word means? This I can not do. Rest assured, there is no globally understood definition of 'transport port' or 'rendezvous point', and the term 'port' has globally understood meaning only in context of AF_INET sockets.